# Kafka RETENTION.BYTES | Manual acknowledgement

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-topic

In case CLEANUP policy is **COMPACT,DELETE** and our acknowledgement is **MANUAL_IMMEDIATE**, and we reach the retention.bytes -> while we were in middle of processing a message, once the logs are cleaned by cleanup policy, would the message be repicked? or we would loose the message?